# Asterisk and Freepbx on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, voip, asterisk

I followed a tutorial to install asterisk 13 and freepbx 13 on Ubuntu 14.04 but I was installing on 16.04. I finish all the steps but when I point my browser to the freepbx server I can't see anything coming up for me to log on to web interface. When I do this `http://192.168.122.180/admin` I get this error

> You don't have permission to access /admin on this server.
>   Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.122.182 Port 80

I want to use Ubuntu not CentOS freepbx system

My Apache configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin systems@domain.com
ServerName domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/admin
<Directory /var/www/html/admin/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your apache configuration is incorrect.  Edit your question and add your apache virtual site configuration.  You're either missing a directory block, or the one you have is restrictive.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin systems@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/ihtml/admin
    <Directory /var/www/html/admin/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed and matched your virtual site directives.  Apache has changed the configuration a bit from 2.2 to 2.4, namely the access control.

> **2.2 configuration:**
>
> Order allow,deny Allow from all
>
> **2.4 configuration:**
>
> Require all granted

As you can see, you're using a 2.2 configuration on what I am assuming is apache 2.4.

The following should work for you.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin systems@domain.com
ServerName domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/admin
<Directory /var/www/html/admin/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,  i did that and its working......... @bc2946088

Answer (score 0):

didn't you encountered what they encountered using FreePBX on Ubuntu 16.04? Check this link https://community.freepbx.org/t/freepbx-install-issues-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/36363. Im planning to use Ubuntu 16.10 on my NUC7i7BNH and install Asterisk and FreePBX. Thanks.